# QueuesNotAvailableException: Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or the broker will not allow us to use it

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

After updating Rabbit MQ version to 3.8 from 3.7 we start getting the below exception

on micro service start up  we are getting

```
{"timestamp":"2021-01-07T12:41:05.738+00:00","class":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory","thread-id":"main","level":"INFO","type":"createBareConnection","logMessage":"Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#5b5e7036:1/SimpleConnection@1e734eee [delegate=amqp://test@172.40.1.237:5672/, localPort= 40702]"}
{"timestamp":"2021-01-07T12:41:05.740+00:00","class":"com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler","thread-id":"AMQP Connection 172.40.1.237:5672","level":"WARN","type":"log","logMessage":"An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)"}
{"timestamp":"2021-01-07T12:41:06.747+00:00","class":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory","thread-id":"AMQP Connection 172.40.1.237:5672","level":"ERROR","type":"log","logMessage":"Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=503, reply-text=COMMAND_INVALID - unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message', class-id=40, method-id=10)"}
```

we are using spring boot

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

we are using `RabbitListener` to bind and create queue

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
        value = @Queue(value = "state.Transaction", durable = "true", autoDelete = "false"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = "state.exchange" , durable = "true"),
        key = "state.Transaction"))
```

```yaml
 rabbitmq:
    host: "rabbitmq-1-xyx.internal.xzy.zzz"
    password: test
    username: test
```

and this test user has all the super permisions
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"

Comment: If you didn't do anything to `RabbitAdmin`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration.java#L190, then you must have more errors in logs to share with us when this `RabbitAdmin` tries to declare exchange, queue and binding for us.

Comment: rabbitmq:
    host: "rabbitmq-1-xyx.internal.xzy.zzz"
    password: test
    username: test

and this test user has all the super permisions rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test "." "." ".*"

Comment: No, that was not the question. I mean before this consumer is trying to start and fail because there is no queue for it, there must be some `RabbitAdmin` activity in the application where it really tries to create those AMQP entities on the broker. What you show is a consequence - we need to see a reason. Why Rabbit Admin was not able to create that queue for us?

Comment: we are getting this during startup logs 
{"timestamp":"2021-01-07T12:41:06.747+00:00","class":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory","thread-id":"AMQP Connection 172.40.1.237:5672","level":"ERROR","type":"log","logMessage":"Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=503, reply-text=COMMAND_INVALID - unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message', class-id=40, method-id=10)"}

Comment: i also update the question

Comment: Looks like you don’t have delays exchange plugin : https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/

Comment: it was working before updating rabbit mq server to 3.8.9

Comment: Well, probably it was enabled before somehow, but now it is not. Try to enable it and let’s see how it works!

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion problem is solved now it was  "rabbit mq server got updated but the Plugin doesn't support current server version "  . 
Actual broker version: "3.8.9", supported by the plugin: ["3.7.0-3.7.x"]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The plugin GH page says it is supported by RabbitMQ 3.8.x: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange

Comment: it was like our infra team update the broker version but the existing version of plugin in not updated and it was outdated we update the plugin version and now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

try to remove RabbitAutoConfiguration from the below code found in the main class.
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={RabbitAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).